# Calling constructor of custom global planner

Tags: ros-kinetic

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi

I have created a custom global planner based on Genetic Algorithm.

I followed this tutorial:

http://wiki.ros.org/navigation/Tutorials/Writing%20A%20Global%20Path%20Planner%20As%20Plugin%20in%20ROS

In the constructor:

GeneticAlgorithmGlobalPlanner(std::string name, costmap_2d::Costmap2DROS* costmap_ros,

**int numberOfIterations, int populationSize, int crossType, float crossProbability, float mutationProbability, int raduis**);

The parameters in bold are specific to GA and used in any implementation for GA

**My question is:**

When I use the planner:

```
<param name="base_global_planner" value="ga_global_planner/GeneticAlgorithmGlobalPlanner"/>
```

**How can I pass these parameters?**

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/380372/calling-constructor-of-custom-global-planner/) by [Eman.m](https://answers.ros.org/users/42689/eman.m/) on ROS Answers with karma: 65 on 2021-06-15

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

You can't (such that they are used by the global planners constructor).

If you plan to use the global planner as a plugin to `move_base` you need to adhere to the respective interface. You cannot simply change the constructor and assume everything works. You'd need to adapt `move_base` to pass the additional parameters, which doesn't really make sense...

However, the other global planners also have parameters that are read from the Parameter Server **after** the Planner class is constructed. I suggest you follow the same route.

---

Originally posted by [mgruhler](https://answers.ros.org/users/2647/mgruhler/) with karma: 12390 on 2021-06-16

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Eman.m](https://answers.ros.org/users/42689/eman.m/) on 2021-06-16**:
Thank you. I will work on that.